# Redirect URI cannot contain newline characters.(Query String)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, query-string, global-asax

I got this error **Redirect URI cannot contain new-line characters.** when run this below code. Am Working `MVC 4` .  hers is my working code .

```
 protected void Application_Error(Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
            {
                System.Web.HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
                System.Exception exception = Context.Server.GetLastError();
                var stackTraceExcep = new StackTrace(exception, true); // create the stack trace
                var stackTrace = stackTraceExcep.GetFrames()         // get the frames
                              .Select(frame => new
                              {                   // get the info
                                  FileName = frame.GetFileName(),
                                  LineNumber = frame.GetFileLineNumber(),
                                  ColumnNumber = frame.GetFileColumnNumber(),
                                  Method = frame.GetMethod(),
                                  Class = frame.GetMethod().DeclaringType,
                              }).FirstOrDefault();


                string FileName = stackTrace.FileName;
                string LineNumber = stackTrace.LineNumber;
                string ColumnNumber = stackTrace.ColumnNumber;
                string MethodName = stackTrace.Method.Name;
                string ClassName = stackTrace.Class.Name;
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(exception.Message))
                {
                    Response.Redirect(String.Format("~/Error/{0}/?errorMessage={1},FileName={2},LineNumber={3},ColumnNumber={4},MethodName={5},ClassName={6}", "App_Error", exception.Message, FileName, LineNumber, ColumnNumber, MethodName, ClassName));//I got this error in this line 
                }
                context.Server.ClearError();
            }
```

What Problem ? How can we solve this ? i have already searched and tried  Google and get some stack overflow answers. but anything does not help me .

Now what i do ?

My Controller action method

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult App_Error(string errorMessage, string fileName, string lineNumber, string columnNumber, string methodName, string className)
        {
            string errorNumber = Convert.ToString(errorRepository.AddError(errorMessage, fileName, Convert.ToInt32(lineNumber), Convert.ToInt32(columnNumber), methodName, className));
            ViewData["message"] = "An error has occurred in the application . The error number is : " + errorNumber;
            return View();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

I think . your filename is null , or Url field . So it's confused and display the error . Now i just changed your code , see the bold lines .

**Edit** :

And your Query String format is wrong . `Please Change ,( comma) to & (and)`

```
 protected void Application_Error(Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Web.HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
            System.Exception exception = Context.Server.GetLastError();
            var stackTraceExcep = new StackTrace(exception, true); 
            var stackTrace = stackTraceExcep.GetFrames()         
                          .Select(frame => new
                          {                   // get the info
                              FileName = frame.GetFileName(),
                              LineNumber = frame.GetFileLineNumber(),
                              ColumnNumber = frame.GetFileColumnNumber(),
                              Method = frame.GetMethod(),
                              Class = frame.GetMethod().DeclaringType,
                          }).FirstOrDefault();


            **string FileName = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(stackTrace.FileName) ? Server.UrlEncode(stackTrace.FileName) : "";**
            string LineNumber = stackTrace.LineNumber.ToString();
            string ColumnNumber = stackTrace.ColumnNumber.ToString();
            string MethodName = stackTrace.Method.Name;
            string ClassName = stackTrace.Class.Name;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(exception.Message))
            {
                Response.Redirect(String.Format("~/Error/{0}/?errorMessage={1}&fileName={2}&lineNumber={3}&columnNumber={4}&methodName={5}&className={6}", "App_Error", exception.Message, FileName, LineNumber, ColumnNumber, MethodName, ClassName));

            }
            context.Server.ClearError();
        }
```

Comment: Now the error is gone . But i get all details in error-message parameter .Other parameters are return null . Why ?

Comment: Your Query String format is wrong . Change ,( comma) to & (and)

Answer (score 10):

You need to URLEncode your exception message with HttpUtility or UrlHelper

```
HttpUtility.UrlEncode(exception.Message)
```

Change your Redirect line as follows

```
Response.Redirect(String.Format("~/Error/{0}/?errorMessage={1},FileName={2},LineNumber={3},ColumnNumber={4},MethodName={5},ClassName={6}", "App_Error", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(exception.Message), FileName, LineNumber, ColumnNumber, MethodName, ClassName));
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message may contain not just newline characters, but also some other formatting.
You need to encode it before sending as a query string parameter:

```
UrlHelper.Encode(exception.Message)
```

Comment: Have you tried on every parameter you're sending that can be string?

Comment: Yes. Please look my question one more time

Comment: Now . That error was solved . But All values are sent used by errorMessage parameter, another parameters are null . why

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Session in (asp.net) or tempdata in MVC to do the same

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score -1):

The message is clear: You have a new line in your query string. Place a breakpoint and do a quick watch on the ofending line to find where is the new line and fix it.

Otherwise this code may solve the problem:

```
String.Format("~/Error/{0}/?errorMessage={1},FileName={2},LineNumber={3},ColumnNumber={4},MethodName={5},ClassName={6}", "App_Error", exception.Message, FileName, LineNumber, ColumnNumber, MethodName, ClassName).Replace(@"\r\n", string.Empty);
```

Comment: Now . That error was solved . But All values are sent used by errorMessage parameter, another parameters are null . why

Comment: You should open a new question for this. However, I don't like at all you exception handling policy, I'd rather write all that data to an error log or database table and redirect to error page with a simple message informing that an error occurred. Users shouldn't be bothered with such technical details, among other possible security concerns.

Comment: Okay sorry ! But i got two problems for this same topic , so i asked that . sorry !